# How can I create a Sidebar Menu in Excel by freezing only a specific column?

Tags: excel, vba, sidebar

I'm trying to create a system in `Excel`, and I want to create a `Sidebar Menu` to facilitate the access to every function of the system.

I already used "`Freeze Panes`" by selecting the cell `B3`, to freeze my header and sidebar, and define the content area.

The problem is that when the user starts to scroll down the page, the menu options goes up, and the user can't see them anymore... I want to prevent this behavior.

Is there any way to do this using Excel functionality or even VBA ? Can I freeze a pane more than once?

**What I want to do:**

[image]

**The problem example:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your second image has `Freeze Panes` at B3 will always keep rows 1:2 visible along with Column A. Since you scrolled down it's not showing the rows that aren't frozen. Your first image where you have `Lock here` would have it show always column A and Rows 1:22. If that doesn't work you can try using a modeless form that would always be visible with hyperlinks that go where you want them to.

Create a userform with a single button on it. In the code behind for the button put in

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1.Index).Range("A1").Activate
End Sub`

Create a standard module with

`Public Sub ShowMeTheForm()
    UserForm1.Show False
End Sub`

You'll have to edit the worksheet Codename to suit your needs but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I thought about using a form, but it's my last option... Can you please explain me how can I setup my worksheet so it "always show column A and Rows 1:22" after freezing at B3? If I freeze my spreadsheet at B22, then my content area would be very small... barely visible. I think my problem is something like "How can I `Freeze Panes` twice in a spreasheet?

Comment: By keeping the view frozen at `B3` you can't do what you'd like. Freezing below you'll minimize your work area as you've said. That's why I suggested a modeless from.

Comment: Hmm... that's kinda sad! Well.. I'm gonna take a look at a few tutorials so I can build my modeless form. Thanks in advance!